# In GTA5 do you have to do the story again in multiplayer mode

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Hi I have two questions

1. If I have completed the story mode on single player do I have to complete the story again when I play in multiplayer/ online
2. If you do have to do the story mode again can I switch inbetween the two without losing any progress in either mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. The Story mode and multiplayer mode are two entirely separate entities, with the multiplayer basically being an open sandbox with level-gated content(weapons, for example, require certain level for you to be able to purchase and modify them).
2. Since there's no story in the multiplayer, no single player saves will be lost. There is a progression but it is separate and stored online, while the single player saves are local and therefore editable(on PC, at least). You can transfer your multiplayer progress(levels, cars, money) from consoles to a PC, should you ever wish to start playing the multiplayer on a different platform.